# Why do I keep getting the error "attempt to index nil with 'Cash' in my script?

Tags: lua, roblox

For a bit of context, I'm making a Tycoon on Roblox to test my knowledge in lua. Everything was working fine until I tried making leaderstats. The first script, which is what makes the Tycoon 
function, is here:

```
     local TycoonInfo = script.Parent:WaitForChild("TycoonInfo")
        local OwnerValue = TycoonInfo:WaitForChild("Owner")
        local Buttons = script.Parent:WaitForChild("Buttons")
        local Purchases = script.Parent:WaitForChild("Purchases")

        local Objects = {}

        function validateHitByOwner(Hit)
            if Hit and Hit.Parent and Hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
                local Player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(Hit.Parent)
                if Player and OwnerValue.Value==  Player then
                    return true
                end
            end
            return false
        end

        for i,v in pairs(Buttons:GetChildren()) do
            local Object = Purchases:FindFirstChild(v.Object.Value)
            if Object then
                Objects[Object.Name] = Object:Clone()
                Object:Destroy()

                if v:FindFirstChild("Dependency") then
                    coroutine.resume(coroutine.create(function()
                        v.Button.Transparency = 1
                        v.Button.BillboardGui.Enabled = false
                        v.Button.CanCollide = false
                        if Purchases:WaitForChild(v.Dependency.Value,90000) then
                            v.Button.Transparency = 0
                            v.Button.CanCollide = true
                            v.Button.BillboardGui.Enabled = true
                        end
                    end))
                end
                local DB = false
                v.Button.Touched:Connect(function(Hit)
                    if validateHitByOwner(Hit)then
                        if DB == false then
                            DB = true
                            if v.Button.Transparency == 0 then
                                local Purchased = DoPurchase(Hit,v,v.Price.Value,Objects[v.Object.Value])
                                if Purchased then
                                    warn("Purchased")
                                else
                                    warn("Can't purchase")
                                end
                            end
                            DB = false
                        end
                    end
                end)
            end
        end

        function DoPurchase(Hit,Button,Cost,Object)
            if Hit and Hit.Parent and Hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
                local Player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(Hit.Parent)
                if Player and OwnerValue.Value == Player then
                    local name = game.Players:GetChildren()
                    local CashValue = game.Players.name.leaderstats.Cash -- Error here
                    if CashValue then
                        if CashValue.Value >= Cost then
                            CashValue.Value = CashValue.Value - Cost
                            Object.Parent = Purchases
                            Button:Destroy()
                            return true 
                        end 
                    end
                end
            end
            return false
        end
```

The next script, which makes the leaderboard and assigns a player that has recently joined to a random available Tycoon, is here:

```
     function FindEmptyTycoon()
            for i,v in pairs(workspace.Tycoons:GetChildren()) do
                if v.TycoonInfo.Owner.Value == nil then
                    return v
                end
            end
            return nil
        end


        game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(Player)
            local Tycoon = FindEmptyTycoon()
            Tycoon.TycoonInfo.Owner.Value = Player 


            local stats = Instance.new("Folder",Player)
            stats.Name = "leaderstats"

            local Cash = Instance.new("IntValue",stats)
            Cash.Name = "Cash"
        end)
```

And then, the script that is stored in all purchasable items to give the Player money, is here:

```
function giveCash(player)
    wait(3.33)
    local Cash = player.leaderstats.Cash
    Cash.Value = Cash.Value + 2
end
```

By the way, these scripts are versions of the original scripts that I've been trying to edit so they can actually work, and I think I've been getting close to fixing the errors. The original scripts can be found here (in order of appearance):

```
local TycoonInfo = script.Parent:WaitForChild("TycoonInfo")
local OwnerValue = TycoonInfo:WaitForChild("Owner")
local Buttons = script.Parent:WaitForChild("Buttons")
local Purchases = script.Parent:WaitForChild("Purchases")

local Objects = {}

function validateHitByOwner(Hit)
    if Hit and Hit.Parent and Hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
        local Player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(Hit.Parent)
        if Player and OwnerValue.Value==  Player then
            return true
        end
    end
    return false
end

for i,v in pairs(Buttons:GetChildren()) do
    local Object = Purchases:FindFirstChild(v.Object.Value)
    if Object then
        Objects[Object.Name] = Object:Clone()
        Object:Destroy()

        if v:FindFirstChild("Dependency") then
            coroutine.resume(coroutine.create(function()
                v.Button.Transparency = 1
                v.Button.BillboardGui.Enabled = false
                v.Button.CanCollide = false
                if Purchases:WaitForChild(v.Dependency.Value,90000) then
                    v.Button.Transparency = 0
                    v.Button.CanCollide = true
                    v.Button.BillboardGui.Enabled = true
                end
            end))
        end
        local DB = false
        v.Button.Touched:Connect(function(Hit)
            if validateHitByOwner(Hit)then
                if DB == false then
                    DB = true
                    if v.Button.Transparency == 0 then
                        local Purchased = DoPurchase(Hit,v,v.Price.Value,Objects[v.Object.Value])
                        if Purchased then
                            warn("Purchased")
                        else
                            warn("Can't purchase")
                        end
                    end
                    DB = false
                end
            end
        end)
    end
end

function DoPurchase(Hit,Button,Cost,Object)
    if Hit and Hit.Parent and Hit.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
        local Player = game.Players:GetPlayerFromCharacter(Hit.Parent)
        if Player and OwnerValue.Value == Player then
            local CashValue = game.ServerStorage.PlayerCash:FindFirstChild(Player.Name)
            if CashValue then
                if CashValue.Value >= Cost then
                    CashValue.Value = CashValue.Value - Cost
                    Object.Parent = Purchases
                    Button:Destroy()
                    return true
                end
            end
        end
    end
    return false
end
```

```
function FindEmptyTycoon()
    for i,v in pairs(workspace.Tycoons:GetChildren()) do
        if v.TycoonInfo.Owner.Value == nil then
            return v
        end
    end
    return nil
end


game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(Player)
    local Tycoon = FindEmptyTycoon()
    Tycoon.TycoonInfo.Owner.Value = Player


    local stats = Instance.new("BoolValue",Player)
    stats.Name = "leaderstats"
    stats.Parent = game.ServerStorage

    local Cash = Instance.new("IntValue",stats)
    Cash.Name = Player.Name
    Cash.Value = 0
    Cash.Parent = game.ServerStorage.PlayerCash
end)
```

```
local amount = 2
local timedelay = 2.33
local currencyname = "Cash"
wait(1)
while true do
    wait(timedelay)
    for i,v in pairs(game.ServerStorage.PlayerCash:GetChildren()) do
        if v:FindFirstChild("leaderstats") and v then
            v.leaderstats[currencyname].Value = v.leaderstats[currencyname].Value + amount
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Everytime you share code as a screenshot, a unicorn dies. Now what do you think happens if you share code as a video?

Comment: Apologies, I thought if I added more code, it would already be too much to read. I'll fix that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
local name = game.Players:GetChildren()
```

Why do you store the list of Players's children in a variable called name? This function returns a table. name would be more suitable for a string.

```
local CashValue = game.Players.name.leaderstats.Cash -- Error here
```

`game.Player`s is https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/Players

I cannot make sense of `game.Players.name` and even less of `game.Players.name.leaderstats`

Did you mean `Player.leaderstats`?

I would expect an error message for `Players.name.leaderstats` before facing an error for `game.Players.name.leaderstats.Cash`

`name` is not a Property of Players so you should not be allowed to index `Players.name`

I'm no Roblox expert but from what I see your code is so off that you really should start with simple tutorials rather than with fixing this code.

I think you should start over and make sure you understand how `Instance.new` is used properly and such things.

Using better variable names will also help.

Comment: The name variable is used to get the Players that join the game. I thought I could store the leaderstats in the Player so that the Cash can be used both as a currency that is used to purchase items in the Tycoon, and so it appears in the leaderboard that's shown at the top right next to their name. Also, in the scriptinghelpers forum, I was vaguely told to "store leaderstats in Player", which I thought was the Player that joined the game, not just`game.Players` (nothing else was said other than to make leaderstats a folder, so I moved here to ask the question). Thank you for the advice though.